# How to send basic auth for nginx and bearer token for API auth

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use a reverse proxy on nginx along with basic auth. My API has a design in such a way where some rest calls are open and some require a bearer token. I see an older post where someone gives an idea to use a separate variable in a request and send it to API. but i want that if the variable not available in query then don't send bearer token to API.
Here is my configuration:

```
location / {
                
                 auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                 auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
                 proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $arg_token";
                 proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
 
                 #proxy_redirect off;
                 proxy_pass https://192.168.0.37/myapi/;
                 #proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_redirect default;
                  
        }
```

So i cant send the request to nginx service:

http://my-server-ip/api/v1/customer?id=12345&token=0pyLQi6CcHtoEJojPTt48qEnqDo/8NGc
but i want that when i need to access a open api URL then no need to send any token in the request but with above setup i must need to send token even empty string as my api can ignore this token

```
http://my-server-ip/api/v1/allcustomers?token=''
```

Is it possible to avoide sending of empty token and solve this within nginx config that if no token found in request then add empty bearer token?

Comment: You can change the API authorization header name to something different. For example, `X-Authorization: Bearer XXX`

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional location blocks to accommodate different authentication schemes. For example, if you have API endpoints at location "/api" that require a bearer token, you can write the location block without server-level authentication. Similarly, if you have open endpoints that require authentication, you can add the NGINX authentication parameters in this block.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35028216)